# Can we find the closed form of this integral $\int_0^1{\frac{\ln\,\Gamma \left( 1-x \right)}{x}\text{d}x}$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

$$
\int_0^1{\frac{\ln\,\Gamma \left( 1-x \right)}{x}\text{d}x}
$$

I met this integral when I intended to solve this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}$.
But I found I had no idea to deal with it.

Comment: Since $\zeta(n+1) > 1$, that series diverges.

Comment: I'm very sorry for my typo, the denominator should be $(n+1)^2$ rather than $(n+1)$.

Comment: Such series are quite intractable. I am pessimistic towards a closed-form in terms of well-known special functions.

Comment: WA says: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28ln+Gamma%281-x%29%29%2Fx+from+0+to+1

Comment: You may use $$log \Gamma(1-x)=\gamma x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty }\frac {\zeta(k)} {k} x^k$$ and the series 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty }\frac {\zeta(k)} {k} x^k$$ converges only for $-1<x<1$

Comment: You can also use this(only helpful after doing integral) $$\acute {\zeta}(-1)-\acute {\zeta}(-1,1-x)=\frac {x(1-x)} 2 +\gamma \frac {x^2 }2-\frac {log(2π)x} 2+\frac x 2 \sum_{k=2}^{\infty }\frac {\zeta(k)} {k(k-1)} x^k$$ Now put the value of $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty }\frac {\zeta(k)} {k(k-1)} x^k$$ from this equation to above obtained integral then apply limits of integral.

Comment: That will give you answer in terms of derivative of Zeta function.The answer which i got is nearly $1.413$